# Word that means "didn't consider the consequences"

Tags: single-word-requests

Title.  I'm looking for a word or expression that means that someone didn't think about the consequences of an action but still executed said action.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Try **reckless**. [ODO definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reckless):

> (Adjective) Heedless of danger or the consequences of one’s actions;
>   rash or impetuous:
>   *"you mustn’t be so reckless"*
>   *"reckless driving"*

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible answers here.

[rash](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rash)

> done or made or doing something quickly and without thought about what will happen as a result

[impetuous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impetuous)

> acting or done quickly and without thought

From here, you can look for synonyms and find **gadarene, heady, precipitous**.

Answer (score 1):

From Oxford Dictionaries, **[thoughtless](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thoughtless)**: Without consideration of the possible consequences

> **E.g.** to think a few minutes of thoughtless pleasure could end in this.

Usage statistics (Google)
[image]